# Python requests session - NO SEARCH RESULTS

Tags: python, session, python-requests

Using Python 3.4 with libraries requests, lxml.cssselect and lxml.html for a screen scraper. Login with user name and password works fine, two or three page links work fine to get me to a search page. Then I post the search request with:

```
import requests
oSession    = requests.Session()
oPage5      = oSession.post( cDomain + cAction4, data = {...})
```

and the result is the same search screen; i.e. none of the search parameters were accepted. This is what I tried so far:

- used b'' and u'' encoding of the string in the data dictionary
- used import urllib.parse to urlencode the data strings (should not be necessary)
- used Google Chrome developer console to check out the form data and copied them into the data dictionary

So, I am running out of options. Can anybody tell me:

- how to find out what the Session object really sends to the server during post?
- does the order of the tags in the form data ,matter? and if so, how to force a certain order (OrderedDict?)
- should I worry about headers? I am not touching them at all. The interactive session shows in Google Console a "Set-Cookie" under Response Headers. The scripted response oResponse.headers does not have this "Set-Cookie" header
- where else to look?

The web site is an older IBM Websphere installation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, restarting my hunt this morning I find my code working. Maybe I just overloaded the web site yesterday??? Thanks to everybody who checked this out.